# How to construct the elm2clu_dict

Tags: python, hierarchical-clustering, hierarchical

I read in clusim (python) documentation the following

```
from clusim.clustering import Clustering, print_clustering
import clusim.sim as sim
c1 = Clustering(elm2clu_dict = {0:[0], 1:[0], 2:[1], 3:[1], 4:[2], 5:[2]})
c2 = Clustering(elm2clu_dict = {0:[0], 1:[1], 2:[1], 3:[1], 4:[1], 5:[2]})
print_clustering(c1)
print_clustering(c2)
sim.jaccard_index(c1, c2)# to find similarity
```

But how the elm2clu_dict is constructed??

Answer (score 0):

The elm2clu_dict has the form of an element_id mapping to a list of cluster_ids:
{element_id : [cluster_id1, cluster_id2, ...]}

You would create this dictionary from whatever clustering method you're using.  See the examples folder for Jupiter Notebook examples.

Other valid clustering data types include:

1. membership_list (the regular format of sklearn clusterings)
2. cluster_list
3. igraph_covers